# Consulta con SUM y Group by SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
    select AvPgEnc.NumAvPg as numero_factura, AvPgEnc.AvPgDescripcion as Descripcion,
    sum(AvPgDetalle.ValorUnitAvPgDet) as monto, AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg as fecha_vencimiento,
     AvPgEnc.ClaveCatastro as clave_catastral from AvPgEnc
inner join AvPgDetalle on AvPgEnc.NumAvPg = AvPgDetalle.NumAvPg
where AvPgEnc.AvPgEstado = 1 and AvPgEnc.Identidad = '080190040112'
group by AvPgEnc.NumAvPg, AvPgEnc.AvPgDescripcion, AvPgEnc.AvPgTipoImpuesto, AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg, AvPgEnc.ClaveCatastro 
order by AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg
```

El cual funciona hasta el momento, pero necesito agregar una columna para quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
select AvPgEnc.NumAvPg as numero_factura, AvPgEnc.AvPgDescripcion as Descripcion,
    sum(AvPgDetalle.ValorUnitAvPgDet) as monto, AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg as fecha_vencimiento,
     AvPgEnc.ClaveCatastro as clave_catastral, AvPgDetalle.RefAvPgDet as declaracion_ic
from AvPgEnc
inner join AvPgDetalle on AvPgEnc.NumAvPg = AvPgDetalle.NumAvPg
where AvPgEnc.AvPgEstado = 1 and AvPgEnc.Identidad = '080190040112'
group by AvPgEnc.NumAvPg, AvPgEnc.AvPgDescripcion, AvPgEnc.AvPgTipoImpuesto, AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg, AvPgEnc.ClaveCatastro, AvPgDetalle.RefAvPgDet 
order by AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg
```

Pero ahora me desagrega los datos y suma por cada registro existente en avpgdetalle. Necesito que me devuelve la suma por los registros de avpgenc.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si agregas `AvPgDetalle.NumAvPg` al `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas poniendo un campo de la tabla detalle (AvPgDetalle) en el group by, por tanto estas agrupando también por este campo y por cada cambio en el dato de esa columna te va a agregar un registro.

Para solucionarlo deberías entender bien cual es el comportamiento del campo AvPgDetalle.RefAvPgDet (declaracion_ic) que necesitas en tu consulta.

Por ejemplo, si necesitas mostrar solo el primer registro de declaracion_ic por cada factura podrías hacer lo siguiente (usando en este caso una subconsulta que no es quizás la lógica mas performante pero se debe entender el concepto):

```
select AvPgEnc.NumAvPg as numero_factura, AvPgEnc.AvPgDescripcion as Descripcion,
    sum(AvPgDetalle.ValorUnitAvPgDet) as monto, AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg as fecha_vencimiento,
     AvPgEnc.ClaveCatastro as clave_catastral, (select top 1 x.RefAvPgDet from AvPgDetalle as x where AvPgEnc.NumAvPg = x.NumAvPg)  as declaracion_ic
from AvPgEnc
inner join AvPgDetalle on AvPgEnc.NumAvPg = AvPgDetalle.NumAvPg
where AvPgEnc.AvPgEstado = 1 and AvPgEnc.Identidad = '080190040112'
group by AvPgEnc.NumAvPg, AvPgEnc.AvPgDescripcion, AvPgEnc.AvPgTipoImpuesto, AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg, AvPgEnc.ClaveCatastro 
order by AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg
```

Otro ejemplo, obtener el valor mas bajo:

```
select AvPgEnc.NumAvPg as numero_factura, AvPgEnc.AvPgDescripcion as Descripcion,
    sum(AvPgDetalle.ValorUnitAvPgDet) as monto, AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg as fecha_vencimiento,
     AvPgEnc.ClaveCatastro as clave_catastral, Min(AvPgDetalle.RefAvPgDet) as declaracion_ic
from AvPgEnc
inner join AvPgDetalle on AvPgEnc.NumAvPg = AvPgDetalle.NumAvPg
where AvPgEnc.AvPgEstado = 1 and AvPgEnc.Identidad = '080190040112'
group by AvPgEnc.NumAvPg, AvPgEnc.AvPgDescripcion, AvPgEnc.AvPgTipoImpuesto, AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg, AvPgEnc.ClaveCatastro 
order by AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg
```

En fin, si necesitas mostrar todos los datos de la declaracion ic y es un dato diferente para las distintas lineas del detalle, entonces logicamente la consulta te va devolver un registro por cada declaracion ic distinta que se encuentre en los datos.

Espero haber sido claro y que se entienda.

Pd. Si necesitas mostrar los mismos datos repetidos por cada Declaracion_Ic, podes dividir en dos la consulta:

```
Select x.numero_factura, x.Descripcion, x.monto, x.fecha_vencimiento, x.clave_catastral, AvPgDetalle.RefAvPgDet as declaracion_ic from
(
 select AvPgEnc.NumAvPg as numero_factura, AvPgEnc.AvPgDescripcion as Descripcion,
    sum(AvPgDetalle.ValorUnitAvPgDet) as monto, AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg as fecha_vencimiento,
     AvPgEnc.ClaveCatastro as clave_catastral from AvPgEnc
inner join AvPgDetalle on AvPgEnc.NumAvPg = AvPgDetalle.NumAvPg
where AvPgEnc.AvPgEstado = 1 and AvPgEnc.Identidad = '080190040112'
group by AvPgEnc.NumAvPg, AvPgEnc.AvPgDescripcion, AvPgEnc.AvPgTipoImpuesto, AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg, AvPgEnc.ClaveCatastro 
order by AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg
)x
inner join AvPgDetalle on x.numero_factura = AvPgDetalle.NumAvPg
group by x.numero_factura, x.Descripcion, x.monto, x.fecha_vencimiento, x.clave_catastral, AvPgDetalle.RefAvPgDet
```

Sdos.
(seguramente hay muchas otras maneras de resolver el problema, solo menciono algunas posibilidades que te puedan resultar útiles)